# Should I submit a partial edit to prevent people downvoting a reasonable question?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

Sometimes I come across a really, really badly formatted post, that actually has a good question in it, [like this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/617696/1).

I start editing it, but in the meantime (before I have submitted) it collects a downvote or two, because of the bad formatting.

Should I tidy it up a little, submit and then continue editing? So that it looks better sooner - even if it isn't perfect. Or should I complete the full edit and ignore the fact the user gets downvotes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say, if there's a *very quick* gathering of downvotes, submit a partial edit, *as long as everything still makes sense* (ie. don't fix something that doesn't make sense without something else also being fixed) - to make it 'look better'.

**But**, after submitting that, use your 5-minute grace period to fully edit it.

I only say this because I have seen questions like this - where the first few minutes gather quite a few downvotes, because people can't be bothered reading the question, they just look at the formatting and -1 (rightly or wrongly).

But please don't just leave the post half-edited - if you start, finish the job - within 5 minutes if possible)

Comment: What if I go over the 5 mins? Does it make a massive difference?

Comment: Not really - it would just make one extra revision , but as long as you're doing something meaningful I'd say that's no problem

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you should do so. If the question is not well-received, it will be rejected as off-topic and you'll get no upvotes.